# How do i ignore specific character that is not always present, with sscanf?

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

my string starts with abc or abcX, and ends with a number.
For example abc0159 or abcX0159.
I want to know if i can retrieve the number with sscanf, no matter if 'X' is there or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
   char str1[14] = "abc1234567890";
   char str2[15] = "abcX1234567890";
   char num[11];

   sscanf(str2, "abc%*c%[0-9]", num); //Correct
   num[0] = 0;
   sscanf(str1, "abc%*c%[0-9]", num); //Removes first digit (wrong).
   num[0] = 0;

   sscanf(str2, "abc%*[X]%[0-9]", num); //Correct.
   num[0] = 0;
   sscanf(str1, "abc%*[X]%[0-9]", num); //Gives emty string.
}
```

Maybe it just doesn't work with sscanf?

Thx.

Comment: Suggestion: `puts(str1 + strcspn(str1, "0123456789"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sscanf(str1, "%*[^0-9]%10s", num);
```

works with both strings, with `*` the value will be read but won't be written into variable, the `10` protects from buffer overflows.

Comment: the %*10 helps me. Because now with sscanf(str1, "abc%*10[^0-9]%s", num); "abc" is still obligatory, but X is optional. But it would be even better if the optional letter could be only 'X', and nothing else. I my practical case it is not 'X', but a quatation mark.

Comment: Anyway, this is a satisfying solution.

Comment: @anonymous yes, it works with quotation marks `"abc\"1234567890"`, it starts scanning on the first digit (10 characters at most)